# Re-enter interactive mode after Ctrl-z

Tags: linux, terminal, shell

In interactive mode (in [Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave), [gnuplot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot), [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29), etc.) I occasionally press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> by mistake.  This pauses the program and kicks me back to the terminal.

Is it possible to re-enter the original interactive mode (with all the stored variables)?

To reproduce:

```
~> octave
octave:1> a = [1:10];
octave:2> ^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 octave
~>
```

How can I recover my session with the variable `a` defined?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

type `fg` and hit `enter` in terminal.

```
   fg [jobspec]
          Resume jobspec in the foreground, and make
          it  the  current  job.   If jobspec is not
          present, the shell’s notion of the current
          job  is used.  The return value is that of
          the command placed into the foreground, or
          failure  if  run  when job control is dis-
          abled  or,  when  run  with  job   control
          enabled,  if  jobspec  does  not specify a
          valid job or jobspec specifies a job  that
          was started without job control.
```

Answer (score 20):

Type the following to pull the job to the foreground again:

```
fg
```

This is because you suspended the job, meaning it's doing nothing while you can't see it. You can actually let a job run in the background too (by entering `bg`). See [Job Control](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `fg` to bring the foreground activity back

OR

You can use `bg` to move the current activity to background.

Answer (score 0):

In linux you could use `reptyr PID_number`.

If for example you had been running vim in your terminal then
first get the terminal PID_number with something like
`ps -ax | grep vim`

then
`sudo reptyr PID_number`

Scroll through open applications and you should see your terminal as it was.

HTH

Comment: `zsh: command not found: reptyr` Not installed by default on all OSes.

Comment: Yes, this package you will have to install, but it works